# Redirect only the homepage for IE users using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internet-explorer, redirect

I am in the process of creating a wordpress site and have an issue with Internet Explorer. The homepage gets jacked up because of an image slider. To fix the issue I have created an alternate homepage that simply doesn't have the image slider in it. I am trying to figure out how to redirect only the current homepage (http://whencancercomesback.com/wordpress) to the alternate homepage (http://whencancercomesback.com/wordpress/index.php/alt-home/) for all IE users (6-10). I would like to do this with .htaccess to keep from having to adjust my functions php file. Below is my current .htaccess code.

Thanks!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ContactForm - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you really need a special case for IE10? If this is for IE < 10 then you should use a conditional comment instead and simply have an IE-only stylesheet.

Comment: IE 10 and 11 look fine. Its mainly 8 and 9. I would say don't worry about it but the site is directed toward an older demographic that will most likely have older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a redirect it would be better to target these browsers ("mainly IE 8 and 9") using a conditional comment and serve an additional snippet of CSS that simply hides this element in these browsers.

In the `head` of your homepage, after your main CSS file:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<style>
#image-slider {display: none}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This targets IE9 and earlier. All other browsers will ignore it (as it's seen as an ordinary HTML comment in other browsers).

Conditional comments (such as the above) can only be used to target IE9 and below, since they were removed from IE10.

Comment: So if I wanted to target 10 and under I would add <!--[if lte IE10]>

Comment: Unfortunately not (as stated in my answer), conditional comments were removed in IE10+. They can only be used to target IE9 and earlier. The idea being that IE10 CSS support is good enough, so you should be able to get it to work. (?)

Comment: Ok I added it to the header of my site and tested it with NetRenderer. It appears to be working. However, I can only see a portion of the home screen. Is there a better tool to view your website on different versions of IE?

Comment: I tend to just make do with the "Emulation modes" in IE11 these days. I've used [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) in the past - although not the most stable of apps. However, if you need to do a lot of testing and/or accuracy is important then a virtual machine is the way to go. More info... http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/developers/articles/5-ways-to-test-your-website-in-old-versions-of-ie/

Comment: If the above "answer" answers your question then please mark it as "accepted" (tick on left hand side below the arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15 rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Much appreciated :)

Comment: I'll give the emulation mode a go. Thanks again for your help.